# More than one could achieve by just VS. couldn't simply be achieved just by

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching an anime a few minutes ago, and an apprentice described his master's god-like power. And he said:

> "Master please, your power is **more than one could achieve by just** training'' (from the anime)

Compared to:

> "Master please, your power **couldn't simply be achieved just by** training'' (from me)

My point here is, as for the **context**, are they both can be considered as related?

Comment: They are related but they don't mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: This reads like you are asking us to proofread the second example. Could you add what part(s) concern you? BTW, I would use "from training" rather than "by training". For "by", usually, it is like "by training (something)..."

Comment: @user3169, I can't quite catch your explanation of "*from training-by"* thing, could you make that one more clear? As for the parts I'm concerned about is they both seem the same, "**by just"** or "**just by".**